# Black Video Screen when attempting to load a video file to react?

Tags: reactjs, video, react-player

I am attempting to load a local video into react using react-player to play the video. I have the basic code setup but I am unsure why the video isn't playing.

I've seen some chatter about the video needing to be in the public folder but is that really necessary? Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/localvideoplay-sltf8?file=/src/App.js) and below is the actual code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import classes from "./app.module.css";

function App() {
  const [videoFilePath, setVideoFileURL] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setVideoFileURL("./assets/beyondTheSea.mp4")}>
          Play
        </button>
      </div>

      {/**VIDEO 1 */}
      <div>
        {videoFilePath ? (
          <ReactPlayer
            url={videoFilePath}
            width="50%"
            height="50%"
            controls={true}
          />
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the video does need to be in the `public` folder as

```
setVideoFileURL("beyondTheSea.mp4")
```

does work, when `beyondTheSea.mp4` is a file in your `public` folder.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/localvideoplay-forked-kbptq?file=/src/App.js:232-303)